# Error occurred when zipkin setup with ELK

Tags: kubernetes, elk, zipkin

I setup zipkin. Zipkin is deployed in a Kubernetes cluster. When it is running without ELK, there is no any backend errors.

I setup zipkin with ELK. For that, I added below environment configuration to zipkin deployment.

```
- name: STORAGE_TYPE
  value: elasticsearch
- name: ES_HOSTS
  value: http://elasticsearch.my.com:9200
```

When I tried to login to my zipkin server, I'm getting this error.

```
2021-09-01 06:04:21.035  WARN [/] 1 --- [king-tasks-1-44] z.s.i.BodyIsExceptionMessage             : Unexpected error handling request.

java.lang.RuntimeException:
        at zipkin2.elasticsearch.internal.client.HttpCall.lambda$parseResponse$4(HttpCall.java:265) ~[zipkin-storage-elasticsearch-2.23.2.jar:?]
        at zipkin2.elasticsearch.internal.client.HttpCall.parseResponse(HttpCall.java:275) ~[zipkin-storage-elasticsearch-2.23.2.jar:?]
        at zipkin2.elasticsearch.internal.client.HttpCall.doExecute(HttpCall.java:166) ~[zipkin-storage-elasticsearch-2.23.2.jar:?]
        at zipkin2.Call$Base.execute(Call.java:391) ~[zipkin-2.23.2.jar:?]
        at zipkin2.server.internal.ZipkinQueryApiV2.getServiceNames(ZipkinQueryApiV2.java:97) ~[classes/:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at com.linecorp.armeria.internal.server.annotation.AnnotatedService.invoke(AnnotatedService.java:331) ~[armeria-1.3.0.jar:?]
        at com.linecorp.armeria.internal.server.annotation.AnnotatedService.lambda$serve0$6(AnnotatedService.java:306) ~[armeria-1.3.0.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at com.linecorp.armeria.common.RequestContext.lambda$makeContextAware$3(RequestContext.java:502) ~[armeria-1.3.0.jar:?]
        at io.micrometer.core.instrument.internal.TimedRunnable.run(TimedRunnable.java:44) [micrometer-core-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-common-4.1.54.Final.jar:4.1.54.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
```

This is the only log,I found in the zipkin logs.
Am I miss any other configuration?

Much Appreciate the responses.